# Perl's print function: print to last filehandle?

Tags: perl

I am confused by this bit of Perldoc:

> If FILEHANDLE is omitted, prints to the last selected (see select) output handle.
>   http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

It seems to say that a naked `print` statement, after writing to a filehandle, will print to that filehandle. I wrote a script to test this...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FILE, '>', 'PrintTest.txt') or die $!;
print FILE "Hello world!\n";
print "Hello.... hello? hello world!\n"; 
close FILE;
```

But the test shows otherwise.

```
$ perl PrintTest.pl
Hello.... hello? hello world!
```

We're writing to STDOUT here, not FILE, which is probably the most sensible result, but seems contrary to that line of Perldoc quoted above. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what "last selected output handle" means? That is the only way I can think to explain this :-p

Thanks in advance ~ ktm

Comment: Hm, think I answered my question. It must be that opening/writing to a file doesn't `select` the file; rather, explicitly invoking `select` selects the new default filehandle. I'll leave this open anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems to say that a naked print statement, after writing to a filehandle, will print to that filehandle.

No, it says it will print to the *last selected handle*, not the *last handle to which you printed*. It proceeds to instruct you to read [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to see how to do it.

```
open (FILE, '>', 'PrintTest.txt') or die $!;
print FILE "Hello world!\n";
select(FILE);                              <----- Missing
print "Hello.... hello? hello world!\n"; 
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a SELECT statement is required to change the default handle from stdout to another.  Then, the selected handle remains in use until changed.